# Memory Collision of Local Variables of Two Funcions

Tags: c++, memory

I have Functions. FunctionA and FunctionB.

```
in FunctionA
{
   char *m;  //Pointed to Shared Memory A
   char outa[600000]
   //Coping the Data into another character array
   memcpy(out, m, 6000000);
   // Now Processing this Data,
   // After Processing I am storing this data.
}

in FunctionB
{
   char *m;  //Pointed to Shared Memory B
   char outb[600000]
   //Coping the Data into another character array
   memcpy(out, m, 6000000);
   // Now Processing this Data,
   // After Processing I am storing this data.
}
```

Now in main, I am creating a thread function which continuously call functionA and functionB, one after the other.

But, sometimes functionA out buffer is getting, while reading functionB out buffer.

But, When i moved those two buffers as member variables of a class, Then there is no Problem of memory collision.

Why it Happened in the First case?
What is the wrong i had done?

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve]

Comment: *"when i moved those two buffers as member variables of a class"* - Oh dear... \*facepalm\* Your functions have local arrays that are destroyed when you exit them. There is no memory Collision happening! You are just having the dividends of UB (pointing to invalid buffers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @RevolverOcelot, please provide MWE.
Also, both 'm' pointers are uninitialized.
Reserve memory of correct size and then use memcpy.

For example:

```
char *m = new char[600000];
```

...

```
memcpy(out, m, 6000000);
```

in both functions.
Remember to free allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

You declared an array of 600.000 bytes (char = 1 byte) and afterwards copied 6.000.000 bytes. I think that caused the confusion.

I would strongly recommend to write such numbers in scientific notation like

```
char test[long(6e6)];
memcpy(.. , .., long(6e6));
```

or

```
char test[long(6e6)];
memcpy(.. , .., sizeof(test));
```

to avoid such errors in the future.